# Homomorphisms between $\Bbb Z_n$ and $\Bbb Z_m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-homomorphism

Let's look at $f:\Bbb Z_{10}\to \Bbb Z_{12}$ . How do you prove that $f$ is uniquely determined by what $f[1]$ is?
What is the order of $f[1]$?

Comment: For any group $G$, if $G$ is generated by set $X$, $G=\langle X\rangle$, and $f,g\colon G\to K$ are two group homomorphisms, then $f=g$ if and only if $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in X$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Because $f$ is a homomorphism,
$$f(n+m)=f(n)+f(m)$$
Use this to determine $f(n)$ in terms of $f(1)$, for any $n\in Z_{10}$.

Also, recall the definition of the [order of an element of a group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_%28group_theory%29). The order of $f(1)$ is just its order as an element of $Z_{12}$. Consider: can we choose any element of $Z_{12}$ to be $f(1)$? Note that
$$\underbrace{f(1)+\cdots+f(1)}_{10\text{ times}}=f(10)=f(0)=0\in Z_{12}$$
because $10=0$ in $Z_{10}$ and $f(0)=0$ because $f$ is a homomorpism.

Answer (score 3):

In addition the other answers, note that both $n$ and $m$ constrain the order of $f([1])$ because $0 = f([0]) = f(n \cdot [1]) = n \cdot f([1])$. Since we also have $0 =  m \cdot f([1])$, we get $0 = \gcd(m,n) \cdot f([1])$. This gives an upper bound to the order of $f([1])$.

Answer (score 2):

Since each of these groups are cyclic, with generator $[1]$, it will determine the rest.  So, if $[m]\in\mathbb{Z}/10$ we have that $[m]=[1]+[1]+\cdots +[1]$ where $[1]$ is added $m$ times.  Then

$$
f([m])=f([1]+\cdots +[1])=f([1])+\cdots +f([1]),
$$

since $f$ is a homomorphism.  But we know what $f([1])$ is and so $f([m])$ is determined.  The order of $f([1])$ is the order of whatever element $[1]$ gets mapped to.