# All group homomorphism from $ \mathbb{Z} _m $ to $\mathbb{Z}_n $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

All group homomorphism from $ \mathbb{Z} _m $ to $ \mathbb{Z}_n $

How could I find every group homomorphism?

Comment: Why do you want to find them?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74629/homomorphisms-between-z-n-and-z-m , http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263063/the-number-of-ring-homomorphism-from-mathbbz-m-to-mathbbz-n , http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273169/number-of-homomorphisms/273171#273171 and probably a bunch of other posts have solutions.

Answer (score 5):

A homomorphism from the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_m$ into any other group is determined by where it sends a generator.  The generator must be sent to an element whose order divides $m$.

In the case of this problem, let $d=\operatorname{gcd}(m,n)$.  For every $d'|d$, there exists a unique subgroup $\mathbb{Z}_{d'}\le\mathbb{Z}_n$.  Map a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_m$ to each generator of $\mathbb{Z}_{d'}$ for all $d'|d$ to obtain all possible homomorphisms.  There are $\varphi(d')$ generators for $\mathbb{Z}_{d'}$, so the total number group homomorphisms is
$$\sum_{d'\mid d}\varphi(d')=d$$
Here $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function.  The above formula is a standard property of Euler's function.

Comment: Why $ d ' $ is considered as $ d'|d $? $\mathbb{Z}_k$ where $ k|n $ can be a subgroup of $ \mathbb{Z}_n$. Then I suppose that $ d' $ would satisfy the condition of $ d'|n $

Answer (score 4):

Hint: each homomorpism $f$ is uniquely determined by $f(1)$.

Answer (score 4):

The map $\phi : Z_m \to Z_n$ given by $\phi(r\mod m) = k r\mod n $ is a well-defined homomorphism if and only if $n$ divides $km$. Every homomorphism from $Z_m \to Z_n$  is of this form.

A homomorphism  is determined by $\phi(1)$ in this case. (Of course, if the group has more
generators, you should check all the generators.)